# GitLab on CentOS 7 (not sending email) after applying recommendations

Tags: smtp, git, gitlab

> [GitLab not sending mails](https://serverfault.com/questions/673609/gitlab-not-sending-mails)

and

> [GitLab email notifications not sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201090/gitlab-email-notifications-not-sending)

have been attempted with no success.

I have an GIT with GitLab as a web management setup.
However, invitation/confirmation emails are not being sent despite using gmail-smtp and above recommendations

[part of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf]

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride none
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None
        #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

[/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb]

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.gmail.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "gitsmt111@gmail.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "smt3214"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "smtp.gmail.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer' # Can be: 'none', 'peer', 'client_once', 'fail_if_no_peer_cert', see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html
# gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_path'] = "/etc/ssl/certs"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_file'] = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/environments/production.rb]

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.eager_load = true

  config.allow_concurrency = false


  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => 'smtp.gmail.com', ## My SMTP Relay/Gateway
      :port => 587, ## SMTP Port
      :domain => 'smtp.gmail.com', ## My Domain
      :authentication => :login, ## Let it be plain as it is inside my LAN
      :user_name => 'gitsmt111', ## This is not required as long as 
      :password => 'smt3214', ## SMTP Gateway allows anonymous relay
      :enable_starttls_auto => true ## In LAN
     }



end
```

[/var/log/maillog]

```
Apr  5 10:50:34 lab-git postfix/pickup[2247]: CDF0D82CD235: uid=1001 from=<gitlab@lab-git>
Apr  5 10:50:34 lab-git postfix/cleanup[15670]: CDF0D82CD235: message-id=<5703faeac7da3_390b1a0e3fc5796b@lab-git.mail>
Apr  5 10:50:34 lab-git postfix/qmgr[2248]: CDF0D82CD235: from=<gitlab@lab-git.localdomain>, size=802, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  5 10:50:35 lab-git postfix/smtp[15674]: CDF0D82CD235: to=<gitsmt111@gmail.com>, relay=alln-mx-01.srx-in.com[173.37.147.230]:25, delay=0.21, delays=0.02/0.01/0.14/0.04, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host alln-mx-01.srx-in.com[173.37.147.230] said: 553 Domain of sender address <gitlab@lab-git.localdomain> does not resolve. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Apr  5 10:50:35 lab-git postfix/cleanup[15670]: 16B2D82CD236: message-id=<20160405175035.16B2D82CD236@lab-git.localdomain>
Apr  5 10:50:35 lab-git postfix/bounce[15675]: CDF0D82CD235: sender non-delivery notification: 16B2D82CD236
Apr  5 10:50:35 lab-git postfix/qmgr[2248]: 16B2D82CD236: from=<>, size=2826, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  5 10:50:35 lab-git postfix/qmgr[2248]: CDF0D82CD235: removed
Apr  5 10:50:35 lab-git postfix/local[15676]: 16B2D82CD236: to=<gitlab@lab-git.localdomain>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0.01/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "gitlab")
Apr  5 10:50:35 lab-git postfix/qmgr[2248]: 16B2D82CD236: removed
Apr  5 12:33:42 lab-git postfix/postfix-script[2105]: starting the Postfix mail system
Apr  5 12:33:42 lab-git postfix/master[2200]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Apr  5 13:11:54 lab-git postfix/postfix-script[2223]: starting the Postfix mail system
Apr  5 13:11:54 lab-git postfix/master[2249]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Apr  5 13:29:25 lab-git postfix/postfix-script[2170]: starting the Postfix mail system
Apr  5 13:29:25 lab-git postfix/master[2197]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Apr  5 13:40:24 lab-git postfix/postfix-script[2281]: starting the Postfix mail system
Apr  5 13:40:24 lab-git postfix/master[2303]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Apr  5 15:06:51 lab-git postfix/postfix-script[2102]: starting the Postfix mail system
Apr  5 15:06:51 lab-git postfix/master[2117]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
[root@lab-git ~]#
```

Comment: smtp.gmail,com is telling you this  ...553 Domain of sender address <gitlab@lab-git.localdomain> does not resolve....

Comment: Are they your real credentials for gmail?

Comment: I've no idea but you know - reading error messages/logs with error messages is a key skill - you really shouldn't expect other people to provide it as a service. Perhaps this isn't the job for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But I do solve a lot of blockers for a lot of people in my department. It is quite challenging to be fluent in all tools out there. Sometimes(most times) s-f folks are very cool on making some things understand clearly for me to help others. But I'll figure this out. Thanks again.

Comment: It's not at all challenging to actually read the information you are posting.

Comment: I read your meta posts and seems you are actually quite reasonable and considerate for others. I'll read more carefully next time. (You are right that this one was obvious). But thanks a lot for the " 
smtp.gmail,com is tell you this" nonetheless.